# Create an Aloha Repository

Tags: repository, aloha-editor

I've been looking at using Aloha for a project but I'm completely stumped by the documentation. I'm trying to create a repository following the documentation and I have this so far:

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
    'jquery': "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min",
    'aloha': "http://cdn.aloha-editor.org/latest/lib/aloha",
  },
});

define(
  ['jquery'],
  function($) {
    "use strict";

    require(['aloha'], function(localAloha) {
      console.debug(localAloha);
      console.debug(Aloha.AbstractRepository);
    });

    return {};
  }
);
```

Now. This tries to pull Aloha and jQuery from an appropriate CDN, and it works fine. However, despite what the Aloha documentation tells me, localAloha is not defined (it appears Aloha doesn't return itself) but that's not a problem since my that point it's in the global namespace anyway.

More frustrating when trying to define a repository is the fact that `Aloha.AbstractRepository` is undefined, despite all the examples, and code from live projects like the Drupal Aloha plugin, telling that all I need to do is extend `Aloha.AbstractRepository`.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here? Aloha looks great, and is perfect for what I have in mind, but it's proven to be very difficult to actually get it working.

Answer (score 0):

here is some code which should help you.

a php script is reading files from direcotries (eg. upload dir) and generates a json file with that information. that json is in the format which can be used by a js file (repository api) to tell aloha editor what's in your repository: http://ge.tt/1VJqium/v/0?c